# Exactly-once semantics in Flink Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I,m trying to test Flink exactly-once semantics with Kafka Source and Sink:

1. Run flink app, simply transferring messages from one topic to another with parallelism=1, checkpoint interval 20 seconds
2. Generate messages with incrementing integer numbers using Python script each 2 seconds.
3. Read output topic with console consumer in read_committed isolation level.
4. Manually kill TaskManager

I expect to see monotonically increasing integers in output topic regardless TaskManager killing and recovery.

But actually a see something unexpected in console-consumer output:

```
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
-- TaskManagerKilled
32
34
35
36
40
41
46
31
33
37
38
39
42
43
44
45
```

Looks like all messages between checkpoints where replayed in output topic. 
Is it supposed to be correct behaviour or i do something wrong?

One snapshot was restored:
[Flink UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hklzz.png)

My Flink code:

```java
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000);
        env.enableCheckpointing(20000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend("hdfs:///checkpoints-data"));

        Properties producerProperty = new Properties();
        producerProperty.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", ...);
        producerProperty.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", ...);
        producerProperty.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTION_TIMEOUT_CONFIG,"10000");
        producerProperty.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG,"my-transaction");
        producerProperty.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");

        Properties consumerProperty = new Properties();
        consumerProperty.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", ...);
        consumerProperty.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", ...);
        consumerProperty.setProperty("group.id", "test2");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer1 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>("stringTopic1", new ComplexStringSchema(), consumerProperty);
        consumer1.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new PeriodicAssigner());

        FlinkKafkaProducer<String> producer1 = new FlinkKafkaProducer<String>("test",  new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper(new SimpleStringSchema()), producerProperty, FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);
        producer1.ignoreFailuresAfterTransactionTimeout();
        DataStreamSource<String> s1 = env.addSource(consumer1);
        s1.addSink(producer1);
        env.execute("Test");
    }
```

Comment: You should provide version of your dependencies, especially Flink and Kafka. Logs from this job would be also useful (e.g. might tell you if your semantic has been changed for some reason).

Comment: Was there any solution to this? From what I'm implementing now on pyFlink 14.2 via DDL and Table API, not seeing a way in enforcing exactly once?

Answer (score 6):

In addition to setting the producer for exactly-once semantics, you also need to configure the consumer to only read committed messages from kafka. By default a consumer will read committed and uncommitted messages. Adding this setting to your consumer should get you closer to your desired behavior.

```
consumerProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_committed");
```

Answer (score 2):

Flink generates checkpoints on a regular, configurable interval. When a checkpoint is restored, Flink rolls back state to the position in the input stream that was last check-pointed (not necessarily the same as last processed/consumed). There are different ways to ensure exactly-once semantics. You could use a producer (sink) that supports exactly-once semantics, see: [Fault Tolerance Guarantees in Flink sinks](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/connectors/guarantees.html).

Alternatively, you could support exactly-once semantics in your consumer. Assuming unique integers that are persisted with multiple workers (parallelism > 1), one way to ensure exactly-once processing is as following:

1. Suppose current checkpoint id is Ckpt N. Store all processed integers (fingerprints of processed events in the case of large events) in the state of Ckpt N. You can achieve that by letting your consumer implements ListCheckpointed interface to store state (fingerprints, or integers in your case) in Ckpt N.
2. Once Flink moves to next checkpoint (Ckpt N+1), filter out all integers stored in Ckpt N's state to ensure exactly-once processing. Stores non-filtered processed integers (or fingerprints of processed events) in the state of Ckpt N + 1 (i.e. discards Ckpt N's state).

You would only need to store fingerprints of processed events (or integers in your case) that occurs between two checkpoints, and discard later when persisting a new checkpoint.