# Exactly once in flink kafka producer and consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to achieve an `Exactly-Once` semantics in `Flink-Kafka` integration. I have my **producer module** as below:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(1000) //Gap after which next checkpoint can be written.
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointTimeout(4000) //Checkpoints have to complete within 4secs
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setMaxConcurrentCheckpoints(1) //Only 1 checkpoints can be executed at a time
    env.getCheckpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(
      ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION) //Checkpoints are retained if the job is cancelled explicitly
    //env.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(3, 10)) //Number of restart attempts, Delay in each restart

    val myProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer[String](
      "topic_name", // target topic
      new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper[String](new SimpleStringSchema()), // serialization schema
      getProperties(), // producer config
      FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE) //Producer Config
```

**Consumer Module**:

```
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic_name", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
```

I am generating few records and pushing it to this producer. The records are in below fashion:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
..  
..
```

and so on. So suppose while pushing this data, the producer was able to push the data till the 4th record and due to some failure it went down so when it is up and running again, will it push the record from 5th onwards? Are my properties enough for that?

I will be adding one property on the consumer side as per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57308590/exactly-once-semantics-in-flink-kafka-producer) mentioned by the first user. Should I add `Idempotent` property on the producer side as well?

My `Flink` version is `1.13.5`, `Scala 2.11.12` and I am using `Flink Kafka connector 2.11`.

I think I am not able to commit the transactions using the `EXACTLY_ONCE` because checkpoints are not written at the mentioned path. Attaching screenshots of the Web UI:

[image]

[image]

Do I need to set any property for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the consumer side, Flink Kafka Consumer bookkeeps the current offset in the distributed checkpoint, and if the consumer task failed, it will restart from the latest checkpoint and re-emit from the offset recorded in the checkpoint. For example, suppose the latest checkpoint records offset 3, and after that flink continue to emit 4, 5 and then failover, then Flink would continue to emit records from 4. Notes that this would not cause duplication since the state of all the operators are also fallback to the state after processed records 3.

For the producer side, Flink uses two-phase commit [1] to achieve exactly-once. Roughly Flink Producer would rely on Kafka's transaction to write data, and only commit data formally after the transaction is committed. Users could use `Semantics.EXACTLY_ONCE` to enable this functionality.

[1] https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html

[2] https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#fault-tolerance

Comment: So I observed a weird behavior or maybe my own lack of knowledge is causing it. When I used `EXACTLY_ONCE`, in my consumer shell, I got the data once the code completed its execution. I didn't receive the records as the code was writing it to the topic. For that, I have implemented `AT_LEAST_ONCE / checkpointing`. If I use `AT_LEAST_ONCE` I get what I need but since the FlinkKafkaProducer only commits transactions during checkpointing, I don't get the behavior when I used checkpointing (with `EXACTLY_ONCE`) as mentioned in the code. Why it is happening?

Comment: Whether you see the uncommitted data in downstream consumers depends on the isolation level [1] of the reader (common concept with transactions).


Setting less strict isolation level (eg. read_uncommited), might have some implications on the guarantees you might want from exactly once.


[1] https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_isolation.level

Comment: The checkpointing interval is very less i.e `1 sec` and the gap between the checkpoints is also `1 sec`. So according to me, transactions should be committed after 1 sec and I should be able to see the records in the consumer shell.  Still, I am not able to get it on the terminal. Also, I haven't set the `read_committed` property yet. What am I exactly doing wrong here or missing?

Comment: That seems correct. Have you checked the checkpoints are completing successfully? Also you could check TM logs to see whether there are any problems regarding transaction commit. One note, there is already a more recent version of the FlinkKafkaProducer (deprecated) called KafkaSink that gets more attention from the community.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. Therefore, I am using the `1.13.5` version of Flink since I wasn't able to implement that in Scala. The documentation has the Java example and when I tried I failed to do it. Could you share any links so that I can try that as well? Meanwhile, I will run the producer with my mentioned path and will try to check the logs as suggested by you if the checkpoints were successful.

Comment: You were right @DavidMoravek. Checkpoints aren't successful using `EXACTLY_ONCE`. I have modified the question with the screenshots.

Comment: Okay, so I resolved it by using `properties.setProperty("transaction.timeout.ms", "900000")` on the producer side. Also, just one question, do I need to set the `read_committed` on the consumer side as well? I don't think so since we are passing the records only after the transaction is successful. So, need your opinion on the same.

Comment: I found the explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961258/how-to-achieve-exactly-once-semantics-in-apache-kafka-connector